# NSUndoManager Delayed Argument Evaluation

Tags: objective-c, nsundomanager, nsinvocation

I am trying to work with NSUndoManager's prepareWithInvocationTarget. I would like to have something like

`[[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] doSomethingWithObject:[self.aMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]]`

where the argument of `doSomethingWithObject` is not evaluated until the `undo` method is called. In other words I don't want the argument to be the current first element of `aMutableArray`, but the first element of `aMutableArray` at the time of `undo`.

Is there a particular part of NSInvocation or NSMethodSignature that I should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in any method call, it just a question of what happens where. If you don't want `[self.aMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]` evaluated now, don't include it in the invocation expression! Instead, make the invocation expression a call to a method where *that method* will call `[self.aMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]`:

```
[[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] 
    doSomethingWithObjectAtIndex:0];
```

...where `doSomethingWithObjectAtIndex:` is where `[self.aMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]` is called.

Comment: Yes, I see. I just thought there might be a way to do it without creating an extra method. Thank you.

Comment: Adding methods in order to adapt your code to the demands of the undo manager is perfectly standard. And for the very reason you have encountered - there is a difference between what you want to do now and what you want to do in the future when/if the user says "undo".